Scrapy web without <a> nodes / href attributes
Trust you are doing well!
I need your support please, I'm trying to scrape this web page: https://servicio.mapa.gob.es/regfiweb#
Once you enter, you must go to:

Buscadores.
Productos.

I'd like to download all the pdf files, but there aren't  nodes with href attributes. Instead there are buttons with data-id(s) thats triggered via javascript to initiate pdf download.
I've trying but totally unsuccessful.
Do you have an idea?
I want to navigate page by pate and download the pdf of every page.
My code:
import scrapy


class SimpleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "simple"
    # allowed_domains = ["x"]
    start_urls = ["https://servicio.mapa.gob.es/regfiweb#"]
    
    def parse(self, response):
        for book in response.css('.col'):
            title = book.css('span ::text').get()
            link = response.urljoin(
                # book.css('a.pdf ::attr(href)').get()
                book.css('a::attr(href)').get()
            )
            yield {
                'Title': title,
                'file_urls': [link]
            }


See this. I'm voting to close this because it's too general and you didn't add any code. If you'll edit your question then I'll retract my vote.

If you open devtools and go to the network tab you can see the url to the "products" page. You can go to here, fill the form and submit it.

If you stay on the page and hit the search button you can see how the page requests the result. I find it easier, si that's what I'm gonna do. You can see the numbers in the end, to me it looks like unix timestamp.

You can verify it (for example with cyberchef).

If we inspect the pdf download button we'll see this:
function(n) {
  n.stopImmediatePropagation();
  n.stopPropagation();
  n.preventDefault();
  var i = $("#exportFichaProductoPdf").val(),
    t = {};
  t.idProducto = parseInt(this.dataset.id);
  exportPdf(i, t)
}

After looking for the exportPdf function this is what you'll find:
exportPdf = function (n, t) {
        $.ajax({
            url: n,
            data: { dataDto: t },
            type: 'POST',
            xhrFields: { responseType: 'blob' },
            success: function (n, t, i) {
                var s, u;
                console.log(n);
                var e = new Blob([n], { type: 'application/pdf' }), r = document.createElement('a'), o = '', f = i.getResponseHeader('Content-Disposition');
                f && f.indexOf('attachment') !== -1 && (s = /filename[^;=\n]*=((['"]).*?\2|[^;\n]*)/, u = s.exec(f), u != null && u[1] && (o = u[1].replace(/['"]/g, '')));
                /^((?!chrome|android).)*safari/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ? window.open(window.URL.createObjectURL(e), '_blank') : (r.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(e), r.target = '_blank', r.download = o, document.body.appendChild(r), r.click());
            },
            beforeSend: function () {
                $('#loadingDiv').show();
            },
            complete: function () {
                $('#loadingDiv').hide();
            },
            error: function (n) {
                console.log(n.status);
                console.log(n.responseText);
                var t = document.createElement('div');
                t.innerHTML = 'En este momentos el documento no está disponible, estamos trabajando para que pueda obtenerlo lo antes posible.';
                swal({
                    title: 'Documento no disponible',
                    content: t,
                    icon: 'warning'
                });
            }
        });
    }

So basically we need a url and the id so we could recreate the request:
import scrapy
import os
import time


def get_timestamp_ms():
    return int(time.time() * 1000)


class SimpleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "simple"
    allowed_domains = ["servicio.mapa.gob.es"]
    base_url = "https://servicio.mapa.gob.es/regfiweb/Productos/ProductosGrid?NombreComercial=&Titular=&NumRegistro=&Fabricante=&IdSustancia=-1&IdEstado=1&IdAmbito=undefined&IdPlaga=-1&IdFuncion=-1&IdCultivo=-1&IdSistemaCultivo=-1&IdTipoUsuario=-1&AncestrosCultivos=false&AncestrosPlagas=false&FecRenoDesde=&FecRenoHasta=&FecCaduDesde=&FecCaduHasta=&FecModiDesde=&FecModiHasta=&FecInscDesde=&FecInscHasta=&FecLimiDesde=&FecLimiHasta=&productosGrid-page={}&_={}"
    base_dir = "downloads"

    def start_requests(self):
        page = 1
        yield scrapy.Request(url=self.base_url.format(str(page), str(get_timestamp_ms())), cb_kwargs={'page': page})

    def parse(self, response, page):
        from scrapy.shell import open_in_browser
        open_in_browser(response)
        for book in response.xpath('//tr[not(ancestor::thead)]'):
            title = book.xpath('./td[5]//text()').get(default="")
            file_id = book.xpath('./td[last()]/button/@data-id').get()
            if file_id:
                yield scrapy.FormRequest(url="https://servicio.mapa.gob.es/regfiweb/Productos/ExportFichaProductoPdf", formdata={"idProducto": file_id}, method="POST", cb_kwargs={"title": f"{title}_{file_id}"}, callback=self.download_pdf, dont_filter=True)

        # pagination
        page += 1
        num_pages = response.xpath('//button[@data-page][last()]/@data-page').get(default=0)
        if page < int(num_pages):
            yield scrapy.Request(url=self.base_url.format(str(page), str(get_timestamp_ms())), cb_kwargs={'page': page})

    def download_pdf(self, response, title):
        filename = os.path.join(self.base_dir, title+".pdf")
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)

You need to ensure that the base_dir exists before you run the code.
This is just an example, you may want to add pagination and search queries.

awesome! Thank you so much for your teaching.
I've changed base_dir = "downloads" for base_dir = "descargas"
But I've this error:
File "C:\Users\gestion.BI\.anaconda\scrapyProject\book\book\spiders\simple.py", line 28, in download_pdf     with open(filename, 'wb') as f:          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Descargas\\Albaugh (Eslovenia).pdf'
Do you know what I'm doing wrong?

Of course I'd like to add pagination, but first of all I'd like to understand this carefully first.
I think that is complex and worths the money,

@LuisMiguel put the bsae_dir in the project's directory and not in the spiders directory. If it doesn't work you can also use absolute path.

Now I understood! Working! Thank you so much!

At this point I'm going to continue to the pagination.

! Done!
By the way:
Following to the navigation I'm thinking in this:
next_page = response.xpath('//*[@id="productosGrid"]/div/div[2]/button[8]').extract_first()     if next_page is not None:         next_page = response.file_id(next_page)         yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)
But I'm obtaining the next error: AttributeError: 'HtmlResponse' object has no attribute 'file_id

@LuisMiguel it's not enough, no need to include it in the request. I added pagination. Also I noticed that some titles repeat so I added the file id in the file's name.
